# How can I get all currently logged in fe_users with Extbase

Tags: extbase, typo3-8.x

Do anybody knows, how I can get all logged in users in TYPO3 8.7 with extbase? Shure, I can get the fe_users sessions, but isnt there an more extbase like way?

**UPDATE:**

> I need to get the uid's of all currently logged in users. It seems
>   that the is_online field holds only the timestamp from the last login.
>   If the user is logged out, this filed has still the timestamp. maybe
>   is reading the fe_sessions really the better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can evalute two fields every `fe_users` record holds: `is_online` and `lastlogin`.
The field `lastlogin` is refreshed on each server access.
AFAIK the field `is_online` is evaluated in the form `now - lastlogin > n`.

So in general you have another problem, as you can not clearly detect which users are active. You only have the information when a user last time contacted the server.
The interval `n` is necessary as an user has no continous connection to the server. He can just read some text before he clicks to another page, but he also could close the browser window every time. And even then, if the session cookie is stored, he might use the website again and can be online immediately. Was he online the whole time?

On contrast to this a user is not even marked offline (`is_online = 0`) if he does an explicit logout.

Comment: I need to get the uid's of all currently logged in users. It seems that the is_online field holds only the timestamp from the last login. If the user is logged out, this filed has still the timestamp. maybe is reading the fe_sessions a better way?

Comment: you may look in this forge ticket: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/71312